# (Python) List comprehension doesn't return an empty string as False

Tags: python, list, boolean

I am doing a coding challenge,
in which I need to

> Write a function that, given a list of values, returns the list of the values that are False.

The coding challenge explained that

> Python will interpret empty values (e.g. 0, (), {}, [], "") as the boolean False.

So, I wrote this code:

```
def find_the_falsehoods(lst):
    return [i for i in lst if i == False]
```

This works for the first test, but in the second test, it doesn't do what I want:

> Test Passed
> FAILED: [] should equal ['']

The tests are like this:

```
Test.assert_equals(find_the_falsehoods([0, 1, 2, 3]), [0])
Test.assert_equals(find_the_falsehoods(["", "a", "ab"]), [""])
Test.assert_equals(find_the_falsehoods([None, 1, [], [0], 0]), [None, [], 0])
Test.assert_equals(find_the_falsehoods([]), [])
Test.assert_equals(find_the_falsehoods([[]]), [[]])
Test.assert_equals(find_the_falsehoods([[[]]]), [])
Test.assert_equals(find_the_falsehoods(["0", 1, "", "[]", [], [""], 0, (), {}]), ["", [], 0, (), {}])
```

What I am doing wrong here? I can't find any relevant results or clues in the comments on the challenge website, on Google or Stackoverflow.

Comment: The first falsehood I see is the text from the challenge...

Comment: `if i == False` doesn't work because `""` is not `False`.  `bool("") == False` would work if you actually convert it. `if i` or `if not i` implicitly convert i to `bool` when evaluated.

Comment: Where did you get this challenge?

Comment: @CodeMonkey So, is an empty string None?

Comment: @KellyBundy Edabit.com 
https://edabit.com/challenge/sEChDwmcHvWcMSmRM

Comment: @kansha no, the empty sting is a string. None is a special language guaranteed singleton, the only instance of its class.

Comment: See [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations). " the following values are interpreted as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true."

Comment: Geez, they even actually wrote `False`, not just False. I'd stay away from that site then.

Comment: bool("") -> False; bool(None) -> False, bool(0) -> False, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that website is just saying technically incorrect things. An.empty tuple, `()` is not `False`, but it is *falsey*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga And the correct term isn't falsey but false.

Comment: @KellyBundy I would say "falsey" is accepted terminology, but if you want to be pedantic about it, you would say "is considered false in a Boolean context" or, going with the terminology in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) "when tested for a truth value"

Comment: In any case most of these would be acceptable*expect* for explicitly saying "is `False`" which implies the actual `bool` value

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The docs consistently say true/false, usually without something superfluous like "considered ... in a Boolean context". Given that, I despise different terminology (in Python context).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is that it checks for strict equality to False. In Python, the () and the boolean False are similar but not exactly equal. The same applies to other "falsy" values like "", [] and {}.

Instead of checking for strict equality to False, you should instead be checking if the value is "falsy". In Python, this is accomplished using the not keyword. This keyword will return True for any value which is "falsy", and False for any value which is "truthy".

Here is the corrected version of your function:

```
def find_the_falsehoods(lst):
    return [i for i in lst if not i]
```

This function uses a list comprehension to iterate over every value in the input list. For each value, it checks if the value is "falsy". If the value is "falsy", it is added to the output list. If the value is "truthy", it is skipped.

Now, the function should pass all of your tests:

```
import unittest

class TestFindTheFalsehoods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_find_the_falsehoods(self):
        self.assertEqual(find_the_falsehoods([0, 1, 2, 3]), [0])
        self.assertEqual(find_the_falsehoods(["", "a", "ab"]), [""])
        self.assertEqual(find_the_falsehoods([None, 1, [], [0], 0]), [None, [], 0])
        self.assertEqual(find_the_falsehoods([]), [])
        self.assertEqual(find_the_falsehoods([[]]), [[]])
        self.assertEqual(find_the_falsehoods([[[]]]), [])
        self.assertEqual(find_the_falsehoods(["0", 1, "", "[]", [], [""], 0, (), {}]), ["", [], 0, (), {}])

unittest.main(argv=[''], exit=False)
```

Comment: Excellent and noob-friendly explanation, thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Well, actually, `0` and `False` are equal